# Convergence vs Boundedness Criteria for Infinite Products

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

The following is an infinite product, with $a_n$ real, not complex.

$$ P= \prod (1+a_n)$$

A common step in deriving convergence criteria is to take the logarithm,

$$\ln(P) = \sum \ln(1+a_n)$$

and then use $1+x\leq e^x$ to establish

$$ \ln(P) \leq \sum a_n $$

This tells us that if the sum is **bounded**, then so is the product $P$.

If we then assert that $a_n>0$, then the sum grows monotonically (no oscillation), and so the boundedness is actually **convergence**.

**Question:** It is commonly stated that if the sum $\sum a_n$, with $a_n>0$, converges then so does the product. Why?

Is it because the partial products increase monotonically too?

Comment: You essentially answered your own question when $a_n > 0$.  Is that what you really want to ask? A convergent series has bounded partial sums and therefore the partial products are bounded. Since the products form an increasing sequence, they must converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $n$, $a_n > 0$ and, hence,
$$P_{n+1} = P_n(1+a_{n+1}) > P_n$$

The sequence of partial products is both bounded and increasing ...

Comment: thanks, sometimes I get so deep the obvious escapes me